# nullable LocalDate causes validation error if empty fields are submitted

Tags: grails, jodatime

If I create a Domain Object with a nullable LocalDate, the scaffolding editor throws a validation error if the date is empty: Cant populate a class org.joda.time.LocalDate without a year

This seems to come from within the Joda [DateTimeStructuredBindingEditor.getPropertyValue](https://github.com/gpc/grails-joda-time/blob/master/src/groovy/grails/plugin/jodatime/binding/DateTimeStructuredBindingEditor.groovy)

Does anyone know how to prevent this validation problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive, but if the issue is coming from the scaffolding, it's possible that it is sending a blank date, not a null one.

I would try to:

1 - Check if the localDate is actually null before you save it.

2 - Add "blank: true" as a constraint. You shouldn't need this, as it's not a string, but it may work.

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/nullable.html